# Aggregating and summing Python dictionary to create new dictionary structure

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset that includes the week-number of running activities, and I want to aggregate the sum of distance and moving time for each week.

**This is the data:**

```
[
    {
        "week_number": 20,
        "distance": 16510.7,
        "moving_time": 4822
    },
    {
        "week_number": 20,
        "distance": 10005.6,
        "moving_time": 3015
    },
    {
        "week_number": 19,
        "distance": 13746.5,
        "moving_time": 4058
    },
    {
        "week_number": 19,
        "distance": 13391.8,
        "moving_time": 4137
    },
    {
        "week_number": 18,
        "distance": 14996.3,
        "moving_time": 4713
    },
    {
        "week_number": 18,
        "distance": 10070.4,
        "moving_time": 3100
    }
]
```

I want to convert it to the below structure without using a library:

```
[
    {
        "week_number": 20,
        "total_distance": 26516.3,
        "Total_moving_time": 7073
    },
    {
        "week_number": 19,
        "total_distance": 30070.4,
        "Total_moving_time": 7100
    },
    {
        "week_number": 18,
        "total_distance": 20070.4,
        "Total_moving_time": 6100
    }
]
```

The closest I have gotten is below, using nested loops, but it's not great for accessing at the front-end:

```
{
"20":
    {"distance":26515,"moving_time":7837},
"19":
    {"distance":58594,"moving_time":18719},
"18":
    {"distance":41346,"moving_time":12796}
}
```

There are many suggestions on StackOverflow around using Pandas, but I want to learn to do it without a library.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create an empty dictionary where the keys are the unique week numbers.
- Check if week number is already in aggregated_data. If it is, add its distance and moving time to the totals. If it's not, we create a new entry for it in the dict.
- Convert aggregated_data to a list of its values, which are the aggregated dictionaries for each week.

```
aggregated_data = {}
for item in data:
    week_number = item['week_number']
    if week_number in aggregated_data:
        aggregated_data[week_number]['total_distance'] += item['distance']
        aggregated_data[week_number]['total_moving_time'] += item['moving_time']
    else:
        aggregated_data[week_number] = {
            'week_number': week_number,
            'total_distance': item['distance'],
            'total_moving_time': item['moving_time']
        }

aggregated_data = list(aggregated_data.values())
```

Comment: Hero!
I hadn't considered the += approach.

I'm fairly new to coding, so this is really appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create dictionaries to store the sums**

```
distance_sums = {}
moving_time_sums = {}
```

**2.Iterate over the data and calculate the sums**

```
 for item in data:
   week_number = item["week_number"]
   distance = item["distance"]
   moving_time = item["moving_time"]
```

**3.Update the distance sum for the week**

```
if week_number in distance_sums:
    distance_sums[week_number] += distance
else:
    distance_sums[week_number] = distance
```

**4.Update the moving time sum for the week**

```
if week_number in moving_time_sums:
    moving_time_sums[week_number] += moving_time
else:
    moving_time_sums[week_number] = moving_time
```

**5.Print the aggregated sums**
for week_number, distance_sum in distance_sums.items():

```
print("Week", week_number)
print("Distance:", distance_sum)
print("Moving Time:", moving_time_sums[week_number])
print() #* this will create new line after each iteration.
```